# License Type of Software with Free Functionality and Trial Additional Functionality

Tags: licensing

I'm developing open source software for about ten years. Now I rebuild my main product into a professional version. I think for it as a successor of the freeware version which is more or less legacy now.

I want to implement the following licensing model:

- After downloading the software to work in Trial Mode with full functionality for a limited period of time (30 days)
- After the trial period has expired, the program will switch to Free Mode with reduced functionality.
- After a purchasing of a license, all features will be unlocked

There will be one program (not separate freeware and a professional).

My questions and doubts are:

- What is the licensing type (for the download servers) Freeware or Shareware or...
- How to announce the program on my website? Can I announce it as a Freeware?

Do you have any advises or recommendations on that business model?

Comment: did you check prir questions here before asking? eg, [How can I compare and contrast open source licenses?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/120308/31260) and [Is there a chart for helping me decide between open-source licenses?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/105344/31260)

Comment: These topics refers to Open Source licensing. My commercial software is not an open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a nice clean, rigorous definition of Freeware and/or Shareware.

Freeware means that the software is at least distributed free of charge, but there may be restrictions on re-distribution, availability of the sources (as in closed source) and it might omit some features that are available in a paid version.

Shareware is even less well-defined than Freeware, but usually means that (after a trial period) the software stops functioning or starts to seriously nag the user to buy a license.

Going by those two definitions, I would classify your software as Freeware and you could mention in the description that the full functionality is offered during the initial trial period.